# TAnimate doesn't work during mousemove event

Tags: delphi, animation

I have tried to use TAnimator during mousemove event.
I wanted to change component's size with TAnimator during mousemove event.
But it didn't animate. It just changed size.
How can I animate during mousemove event?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Ani;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure Button1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Single);
    procedure Button1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  private
    IsMouseDown: Boolean;
    PtX, PtY: Single;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  IsMouseDown := True;
  PtX := X;
  PtY := Y;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
var
  Anime: TAnimator;
begin
  if IsMouseDown then
  begin
    Button1.Position.X := Button1.Position.X + X - PtX;
    Button1.Position.Y := Button1.Position.Y + Y - PtY;

    Anime := TAnimator.Create;
    try
      Anime.AnimateFloat(Button2, 'Width', 400, 1);
    finally
      Anime.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  IsMouseDown := False;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Animation operates over time. That implies a timer.  Your OnMouseMove event is not giving TAnimator time to run.  Besides, it makes no sense to use OnMouseMove to drive animation. What are you really trying to accomplish? What is the effect you want?

Comment: Thank you. I am making puzzle game now. So I hoped I could animate with TAnimate when mouse moves TButton objects. I don't know how can I  make it.

Comment: It is still unclear WHAT you are trying to animation and WHY. What is the EFFECT you want? User does X, Y happens, what are X and Y?

Comment: Thank you. TButtons is piece of game. I'd like to start animating (Width of TButton) when mouse starts moving.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this instead:

```
var
  Anim: TFloatAnimation = nil;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if Button <> TMouseButton.mbLeft then Exit;
  IsMouseDown := True;
  PtX := X;
  PtY := Y;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
begin
  if not IsMouseDown then Exit;

  Button1.Position.X := Button1.Position.X + X - PtX;
  Button1.Position.Y := Button1.Position.Y + Y - PtY;

  // FYI, you can configure this at design-time as well...
  if Anim = nil then
  begin
    Anim := TFloatAnimator.Create(Button2);
    Anim.Parent := Button2;
    Anim.PropertyName := 'Width';
    Anim.Duration := 1;
    Anim.StopValue := 400;
    Anim.StartFromCurrent := True;
  end;

  if (not Anim.Running) and (Button2.Width <> 400) then
    Anim.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if Button <> TMouseButton.mbLeft then Exit;
  IsMouseDown := False;
  if Anim <> nil then
    Anim.Stop;
end;
```

Refer to the following for more information:

[FireMonkey Animation Effects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/FireMonkey_Animation_Effects)

[Using FireMonkey Animation Effects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_FireMonkey_Animation_Effects)

[Create Floating Animation With TAnimateFloat In Delphi Firemonkey](http://www.fmxexpress.com/create-floating-animation-with-tanimatefloat-in-delphi-firemonkey/)

[FMX.Ani.TFloatAnimation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Ani.TFloatAnimation)

Comment: Great! I almost give up about this. but this code worked. Thank you.